# How to run ProgressBar Form in new thread and manage it using C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I have simple form with progress bar:

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrM7Z.png

I want start progress bar form before start hard method.

For progress bar i need new thread.

My code is:

```
        Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate () {
            new ProgressBarForm().Visible = true;
        });
        myThread.Start();
        hardMethodForAlongTime();
```

But if I run the code my progress bar lag and not working.

How can I do this? And, can i stop thread using `myThread.Stop()` after `hardMethodForAlongTime()`? Or is there any better solution?

```
        Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate () {
            new ProgressBarForm().Visible = true;
        });
        myThread.Start();
        hardMethodForAlongTime();
        myThread.Stop(); //stop?
```

Thank you for your replye.

Comment: No, the hard work should be done on the background thread and the progressbar should remain on the UI thread.

Comment: @Jens I can't run `hard work` in new thread, because this `hard work` using components from actual form...

Comment: That smells like very very flawed code in the first place. Maybe add some more code to your question on what you are actually doing. The progressbar is probably the least of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity use BackgroundWorker. There is a lot of samples with BackgroundWorker and ProgressBar. You can see this one [C# BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)